# The concept of building a blockchain app without transaction

Tags: blockchain, decentralized-applications

I want to build a blockchain application for users to check the authenticity of data on my product.
I am planning to put a QR code on my products for users to scan it and reach my blockchain application (e.g. website) to check the production date for the product.
Since I know people will trust my product when I applied blockchain (immutable) concept.

However I have researched blockchain app development tutorials for a period of time. Those tutorials are teaching with transaction and requiring to use plugin like meta-mask. My project doesn't involved any transaction, just require to store the production date data to database. But I don't know what framework or language that I should use.

Should the project involve Ethereum? Smart contract? or other concepts?

The main purpose of my project is to build a blockchain database that cannot be modify once wrote. And then allow the users to reach my application to see the production date of the product make sure the authenticity.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use an append-only database and just call it blockchain? Blockchain is not good as simply an "immutable-database"

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER. ITS JUST  BIG COMMENT**

Your customers will not need meta-mask or transactions to see the production date of the products.

But to build the product and production date mapping you need to use transaction. Storing something in blockchain means changing it. For that you must create a transaction and pay some transaction fee.

As for your customers, they will not change the blockchain. They will just view some data on the chain. Its free to view data of a blockchain and it does not require transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! One thing I don't really know is "For that you must create a transaction and pay some transaction fee." Why do I need to pay some transaction fee? My blockchain database is not standalone or own by me?

Comment: 1. When you want to store data in a blockchain you create a transaction, some transactions together makes a `block`, this block needs to be mined by the miners worldwide to be verified and authenticated, miners are paid in tokes for their effort. part of the payment comes from the owners of the transaction 2. You can think of blockchain as a public database. You can see all information stored in blockchain. https://etherscan.io here you can see all the data stored in the ethereum main-net.

Comment: So for the part of verifying and authenticating by miners, how can I develop this function? Can I do the verifying and auth part by my own? or this part that I should find external miners to verify it because of the concept of blockchain? Otherwise, verifying by my own is not blockchain. Then, how to find miners?  Thanks!

Comment: Do some research of your own on how `blockchain` and `smart contract` works. You can find good courses on udemy.